# DXA website header and footer do not work on DXA 2.1

Tags: dxa, sites-9, dxa-2.1

I am working on a Sites 9 + DXA 2.1 box with the out-of-the-box example website. I noticed that the header and footer are not working. What could be amiss?

[image: Scheenshot]

The header include page is published and available on the site at http://localhost:8852/system/include/header.html

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed!,  you missed to Installing the DXA Model Extension in content service.

Try the following steps to fix:

1. Create the **extensions** folder in content service root.

   2. Copy the \dxa\cis\dxa-model-service-extension\udp-content-dxa-extension-assembly-11.0.0-1047-core.zip file to **extensions** folder
   3. UnInstall the Tridion SessionContent Service
   4. Re-install the service by this below command:

> .\installService.ps1 --auto-register
>   --plugin=./extensions/udp-content-dxa-extension-assembly-11.0.0-1047-core.zip

I hope it helps

Comment: If one needs to verify if the DXA model extension is installed: Look for a folder named something like `plugins\udp-content-dxa-extension-assembly-11.0.0-1047-core` inside the DXD content service (or session content service) installation directory.